# __cdecl calling convention not work on msvc x64

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, calling-convention

Just a test for `__cdecl` calling convention.

It's a cmake project and only have 1 source file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define CALL_CONVENTION __cdecl

void CALL_CONVENTION f(int a, int b)
{
    printf("%d, %d", a, b);
}

int main()
{
    f(1, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} /FA")` to output the assembly code.

and when I build with `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15"`, It's build a 32bit application, and every thing is in anticipation:

```
...
; Line 12
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
; Line 13
    push    2        ; <------- argument 2
    push    1        ; <------- argument 1
    call    _f       ; <------- call function
    add esp, 8
; Line 15
    xor eax, eax
; Line 16
    cmp ebp, esp
    call    __RTC_CheckEsp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
_main   ENDP
...
```

You can see the arguments is passed by `push 2` and `push 1` instructions, it's `__cdecl` call convention.

But if I'm using `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 Win64"` to build a 64bit application, the `__cdecl` annotation seems not work (arguments not passed by stack):

```
...
; Line 12
$LN3:
    push    rdi
    sub rsp, 32                 ; 00000020H
    mov rdi, rsp
    mov ecx, 8
    mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
    rep stosd
; Line 13
    mov edx, 2        ; <------ argument 2
    mov ecx, 1        ; <------ argument 1
    call    f         ; <------ call function
; Line 15
    xor eax, eax
; Line 16
    add rsp, 32                 ; 00000020H
    pop rdi
    ret 0
main    ENDP
...
```

the arguments is passed by register `edx` and `ecx`, not passed by stack.

So why arguments not passed by stack in x64 even if I specify `__cdecl` and what should I do if I want do same things in x64 environments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

x64 has it's own calling conventions.

[Microsoft docs `__cdecl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cdecl?view=vs-2019)

> On ARM and x64 processors, __cdecl is accepted but typically ignored by the compiler. By convention on ARM and x64, arguments are passed in registers when possible, and subsequent arguments are passed on the stack. In x64 code, use __cdecl to override the /Gv compiler option and use the default x64 calling convention.

[`Microsoft docs x64 calling convention`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019)

> The x64 Application Binary Interface (ABI) uses a four-register fast-call calling convention by default. Space is allocated on the call stack as a shadow store for callees to save those registers. There's a strict one-to-one correspondence between the arguments to a function call and the registers used for those arguments. Any argument that doesn’t fit in 8 bytes, or isn't 1, 2, 4, or 8 bytes, must be passed by reference.
>
> ...
>
> Integer arguments are passed in registers RCX, RDX, R8, and R9

You can see it using ECX and EDX for the `int a` and `int b` (as they are 32bits, while the full RCX and RDX is 64bits).

[`__stdcall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/stdcall?view=vs-2019), [`__fastcall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fastcall?view=vs-2019) and [`__thiscall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/thiscall?view=vs-2019) are also ignored. [`__vectorcall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/vectorcall?view=vs-2019) is available (the /Gv switch makes it default) and is another register calling convention, but compared to the x64 default it can use registers in more cases and has some other rule differences.

Comment: So it's impossible to pass arguments with only stack in x64 architecture?

Comment: Well, if you write assembler, you can do what you like with the `call` instruction, its not a hardware limitation, but no, I don't believe you can make the compiler do it. The x64 ABI is very close, with the "shadow store", but for performance reasons, it doesn't actually write the data to it, the intention being that the *called* function does the write/`mov` if need be.