# parameters to function: differences 32-64 bit

Tags: c++

I did a "generic" function used as a callback function to have different types of parameters defined by an external script.
now i am porting the program to 64bit OS.
I found some differences in the parameters passed to the function.
The following code does not work with the 64-bit platform but it works at 32bit
When compiled for 64bit the parameters of the function are moved 40 bytes forward
Any idea to workaround?

```
typedef struct TPar
{
  char c[500];
}TPar;

int __cdecl f2(int p1, int p2)
{
//   int x1 = (int)*(&p1 + 12);
   int x1 = p1;
   int x2 = p2;
   return  x1 + x2;
 }
 
typedef int(__cdecl* FUNCION_TEMPLATE)(TPar);
int main()
{
  TPar FP;
  int intvalue = 1;
  memcpy(&FP + 0, &intvalue, sizeof(int));
  intvalue = 2;
  memcpy(&FP.c[4], &intvalue, sizeof(int));

  FUNCION_TEMPLATE tf2;
  tf2 = (FUNCION_TEMPLATE)&f2;
  tf2(FP);        //32 bit OK        64bit NO
 
}
```

Comment: Casting function pointers this way is undefined behaviour. `cdecl` is not the same for x64 and x86 - see [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612188/cdecl-calling-convention-not-work-on-msvc-x64).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 3):

The lines `tf2 = (FUNCION_TEMPLATE)&f2; tf2(FP);` have undefined behaviour. That it behaves how you expect it to work on one platform and doesn't on another means you were unlucky when you first wrote that.

Here's a program with defined behaviour that does similar

```
struct TPar
{
  char c[500];
}

int __cdecl f2(const TPar & FP)
{
  int x1;
  int x2;
  memcpy(&x1, FP.c, sizeof(int));
  memcpy(&x2, FP.c + sizeof(int), sizeof(int));
  return x1 + x2;
}

using FUNCION_TEMPLATE = int(__cdecl*)(const TPar &);

int main()
{
  TPar FP;
  int intvalue = 1;
  memcpy(FP.c, &intvalue, sizeof(int));
  intvalue = 2;
  memcpy(FP.c + sizeof(int), &intvalue, sizeof(int));

  FUNCION_TEMPLATE tf2 = f2;
  tf2(FP); // Fine for both
}
```

However C++ has better ways of binding arguments to callbacks, e.g.

```
int __cdecl f2(int p1, int p2)
{
  return p1 + p2;
}

using FunctionTemplate = std::function<int()>;

int main()
{
  FunctionTemplate tf2 = [x1 = 1, x2 = 2](){ return f2(x1, x2); };
  tf2(); // Fine for both
}
```

Comment: I don't know the function parameters type.
this is the reason because i passed a generic array.
before to call the function the program reads from a template the function parameters type (from a text template)
then fill the buffer and the call the function that was loaded from a DLL. 
With 32bit OS was easy because the parameters follow the buffer, with the 64bitOS there is
different convention to pass the parameters.
Maybe there is a way pass a buffer so that the function has the correct values in the parameters

Comment: @Emanuele No, and you should give up on this method. *somewhere* has to know the argument types, and that somewhere can make an object that reads out of a `TPar` into arguments for a call.